# Find subdirectory with specific name

Tags: php, directory

For a php application I want to search directories for specific subdirectories where I want to require all files in this directories.

The path would look like so:

```
/app/*/route/*.php
```

How can I do this?

Comment: maybe there is some class available but there is no built in function. you need to `glob()` recursively and filter file/dirs by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [**glob**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function help you in achieving this.

```
glob('/app/*/route/*.php');
```

For requiring all those files can use this

```
foreach(glob('/app/*/route/*.php') as $file)
{
     require_once $file;
}
```